# No puedo escribir un diccionario desde un archivo de texto cuando trato de manejar unicode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, ascii, unicode

Quiero usar una lista de palabras de forma diccionario  para crear un archivo de texto que contenga una gran matriz de todos los recuentos de palabras para cada uno de los blogs.

Adapto el código de este archivo, que proviene de Programming Collective intelligence escrito por Toby Segaran. Fue escrito en python 2 y quiero utilizar python 3. No sé porqué pero el  intenta de manejar unicode con `blog = blog.encode('ascii','ignore')`:

```
# use la lista de palabras y blogs para crear un archivo de texto 
# que contenga una gran matriz de todos los recuentos de palabras 
# para cada uno de los blogs
out=open('blogdata.txt','w')
out.write('Blog')
for word in wordlist: 
    out.write('\t%s'%word)
out.write('\n')
for blog,wc in wordcounts.items():
    # tratar con unicode fuera del rango de ascii
    blog = blog.encode('ascii','ignore')
    out.write(blog)
    for word in wordlist:
        if word in wc:
            out.write('\t%d' % wc[word])
        else:
            out.write('\t0')
    out.write('\n')
```

Pero me devuelva

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-ed0124699e6c> in <module>
      8     #deal with unicode outside the ascii range
      9     blog = blog.encode('ascii','ignore')
---> 10     out.write(blog)
     11     for word in wordlist:
     12         if word in wc:

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Aquí está una parte de `wordcounts`:

```
{'Le Monde.fr - Actualités et Infos en France et dans le monde': {'comprendre': 1,
  'l': 27,
  'affaire': 4,
  'vincent': 2,
  'lambert': 2,
  'en': 9,
  'dates': 1,
  'depuis': 2,
  ...
```

Me pregunto si sería mejor hacerlo en un archivo CSV.

Answer (score 1):

`blog.encode('ascii','ignore')` te convierte el contenido de la variable `blog` en un set de bytes.

Si usas Python 3+, por defecto los Strings trabajan en codificación UTF-8, por lo que simplemente tienes que abrir `blogdata.txt` en dicha codificación y olvidarte del `encode`:

```
out=open('blogdata.txt','w',encoding="utf-8")
```